# Flex DataGrid Add New row via single click event

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I am trying to implement the following functionality:

Flex data grid has 1 default row created. When user clicks on the second row, a new row needs to be created and made editable.

Here is what works already - user tabs over the columns and when the user tabs while in the last column, a new row is created with default values.

Here is also what already works - user click a button outside the grid, which adds a new row.

(itemEditBegin and itemEditEnd have been implemented)

Here is what does NOT work: When I "single click" on the second row (no data yet - row is null), how do I detect that the currently clicked row is the second row and make it editable? Can I figure out the rowIndex from MouseEvent and use this to add a new row?

Find code below:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" editable="true" click="clickEvent(event)"
     itemEditEnd="endEdit(event)" itemEditBegin="beginEdit(event)" variableRowHeight="true" >

private function clickEvent(ev:Event):void
{
    var i:Object = MouseEvent(ev).currentTarget;
        // is this the right event?
}
```

Comment: It makes it much easier to read if you format your code by adding some space before each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no data, there won't be any row or itemRenderer and hence technically there is no row index. The `e.target` would contain the `ListBaseContentHolder` and `e.currentTarget` would contain the DataGrid itself. However you can use the mouse-y position to calculate what row would have been present at the clicked location. Here is a dirty little trick to do it - it's not thoroughly tested and hence might fail for edge cases.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical"
    xmlns:local="*" creationComplete="create();">
    <mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" editable="true" click="clickEvent(event)"
     variableRowHeight="true" >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="d"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn/>
    </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.listClasses.ListRowInfo;
            import mx.controls.listClasses.ListBaseContentHolder;
            private function clickEvent(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if(!(e.target is ListBaseContentHolder))
                    return;
                var holder:ListBaseContentHolder = 
                    ListBaseContentHolder(e.target);
                var rowIndex:Number = -1;
                var length:Number = holder.rowInfo.length;
                var rowInfo:ListRowInfo;
                for(var i:Number = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    rowInfo = holder.rowInfo[i];
                    if(e.localY > rowInfo.y && 
                        e.localY < rowInfo.y + rowInfo.height)
                    {
                        rowIndex = i;
                        break; 
                    }
                }
                trace("Clicked on " + rowIndex);
            }
            private function create():void
            {
                myGrid.dataProvider = [{d:"A"},{d:"B"}];
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: I just found that when one of the columns of the grid contains a custom combobox, and you click on a 'non-empty' grid row on the combobox area, e.target is still of type ListBaseContentHolder (and not of type itemrenderer). So the below check for target type alone is not sufficient:

if(!(e.target is ListBaseContentHolder))
      return;

The way I worked around it is to track using Boolean if the grid has data or not.

If there is a better way of doing it, let us all know!

Answer (score 0):

Great question, DataGrid supports selection of objects in the DataGrid's dataProvider. But it does not allow easy selection/mouseOver of rows which do not have items in them (null rows).

1) I would either put a dummy row at the end of the DataGrid, so that way it can be easily selected by the DataGrid.
2) Otherwise, I would check to see if mouseX/mouseY are within the parameters of the null-row you just clicked on (using the null-row's global X,Y,width,height properties).

Let me know what works.